# Error al acceder a propidades de clase cambiadas por metodo interno de la clase por $.ajax

Tags: javascript, context

tengo una clase JAVASCRIPT que funciona bien y basicamente es asi:

```
class Account {

    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.email = "";
        this.dni = "";
        this.firstname = "";
        this.lastname = "";
    };
    
    clear() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.email = "";
        this.dni = "";
        this.firstname = "";
        this.lastname = "";
    }
    
    load() {
        var apiUrl = "https://www.direccion-del-sitio-web.com/api";
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'token': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
            },
            url: apiUrl,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {},
            context: this,
            success: function(response) {
                
                console.log(response); // ==> La respuesta trae de forma correcta los valores 
    
                if (response.code === 200) {
                    this.id = response.data.id; // ==> response.data.id es correcto 
                    this.dni = response.data.dni;  // ==> response.data.dni es correcto 
                    this.firstname = response.data.firstName;  // ==> response.data.firstName es correcto 
                    this.lastname = response.data.lastName; // ==> response.data.lastName es correcto 
                } else {
                    this.clear();
                }
            }
        });
    };

}
```

El problema es el siguiente: Luego la implemento asi: `let $account = new Account();`

Cuando llamo al método `$account.load()` "TODAS" las propiedades regresan `undefined`

He investigado y he leido algo de que la configuración de $.ajax debe tener `context:this` pero aun, sí lo coloco, el resultado es el mismo y la información en la web es casi nula (al menos en español).

No logro entender porque si desde la clase por ajax se cambian los valores de los atributos de forma correcta, al tratar de leerlos en la implementacion de la clase no se puede acceder a la propiedades de forma correcta, todas regresan "undefined"

Agradrezco cualquier orientacion porque no he podido conseguir ejemplos de clases que trabajen de esa manera y ya la cabeza me duele de darle tantas vueltas a algo tan básico.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: si verificaste que las propiedades dentro de response.data si sean las correctas? probe tu codigo y me muestra y asigna las propiedades correctamente, la unica explicacion que le veo seria que esas propiedades no estuvieran definidas en response.data, puedes poner un debugger; y verificarlas

Comment: Saludos, gracias por tu apoyo, ya consegui las solucion, era un error mio, en lugar de asignar asi: `this.id = response.data.id` debia hacerlo asi: `this.id = response.data[0].id` porque era, por decirlo asi, un arreglo lo que viene desde el servidor. Pero si quisiera copnseguir mas informacion y ejemplos sobre el `context: this` y su funcionamiento.